# Wordpress Shortcode If/else Returning Double Content

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

The code below echoes either a MailChimp form or Aweber form depending on the value of $os which is set by a theme option select/dropdown (option framework plugin).  I have confirmed that the select does work, the problem is that it spits out two Mailchimp forms or two Aweber forms

```
function optin() {
$chimp_form_action = of_get_option('chimp_form_action');
$aweber_name = of_get_option('aweber_name');
$os = of_get_option('optin_select');

if($os == 1) {
   echo '
        <form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
        <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="' . $aweber_name .'" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou-coi.htm?m=text" id="redirect_1b2ae0ccfba411490452fea07ff6cd9a" />
        </div> 
             <ul id="">
                  <li><input id="awf_field-57234841" type="text" name="name" class="text" value=""  tabindex="500" /></li>
                  <li><input class="text" id="awf_field-57234842" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501"  /></li>
                  <li><input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="502" /></li>
             </ul>
        </form>
       ';
   } else {

   echo '
        <form action="' . $chimp_form_action . '" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
             <ul id="optin">
                  <li><input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="text" name="FNAME" id="mce-FNAME"></li>
                  <li><input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="text" name="EMAIL" id="mce-EMAIL"></li>
                  <li><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" id="mc-embedded-subscribe"></li>
             </ul>
        </form>
       ';
}
}
add_shortcode('subscribe', 'optin');
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mQv7.png  **<<< IMAGE**

I'd be very thankful for someone who can lead me to a solution that produces 'one each' as opposed to 'two each' optin forms.

Thanks!!

EDIT: The code above echoes to Chimp forms or two Aweber forms, not one each for a total of two.

**UPDATED Working code:**

```
function optin() {
$chimp_form_action = of_get_option('chimp_form_action');
$aweber_name = of_get_option('aweber_name');
$os = of_get_option('optin_select');

if($os == 1) {
   $optform = '
        [aweber form code here]
       ';
   } else {

   $optform = '
        [mailchimp form code here]
       ';
}
return $optform;
}
add_shortcode('subscribe', 'optin');
```

Comment: If it's just a plain echo string, would the same, double results be displayed?

Comment: It does.  With Aweber selected and echoing the string "Aweber Test", "Aweber Test" was printed twice, same with MC.

Comment: So in the related theme file the function is called twice! you should check it.

Comment: @revo I wish that were the case but it's called only once in functions.php

Comment: It's fixed.  I replaced each echo with $optform = '[form code]'.  And then returned $optform.  See working code above.  Thanks for your input @revo and @jhuangweb!